# MYSQL 4 Table Query

Tags: mysql

I could use some expert advice with a MYSQL query I'm trying to put together.

What i would like to do:

I'm trying to create a page that will allow users to perform an advanced search across multiple tables.

The 4 tables are:

```
members, profiles, skills, genre

Members:
*********************************
id | member_id | login | zipcode
*********************************

Profiles:
*********************************************************************
id | member_id | exp | commitment | practice | gigs | availability 
*********************************************************************

Skills:
************************************************************************
id | member_id | lead_vocals | background_vocals | guitar | bass| drums
************************************************************************

 Genre:
********************************************************************************
id | member_id | alternative | classic_rock | modern_rock | blues | heavy_metal
********************************************************************************

Skills and Genre represent check box values checked or not (1 or 0)
```

The search form would be a series of checkboxes and dropdowns that would allow a user to specify the specific items they want to search for.

What I need help with:

I need help coming up with the best way to put this query together.  I've been reading up on Joins, Unions, Sub Queries and Derived tables.  I can do some basic queries and get part of the data for example:

```
SELECT members.member_id FROM members LEFT JOIN skills ON members.member_id  = skills.member_id WHERE skills.leadvocals = 1
```

However I just cant seem to wrap my head around putting it all together.

```
An example of the search criteria would look something like this:

A user fills out the form and wants to search for all members with  (members table)  zipcode = 11111 OR zipcode = 22222 (profiles table) commitment = ANY, practice = ANY, gigs = 1, availability = ANY  (skills table) lead_vocals = 1 and lead_guitar = 1 (genre table) alternative = 1, modern_rock = 1, heavy_metal = 1
```

Note I already have the logic to calculate the zipcode distance and return a list of zip codes in the range.

At the end of the day the query just needs to return a list of results with member_id and login from the members table that match the criteria.

I'm not looking for somebody to just provide that answer (although I wouldn't mind the answer :)) I learn better by trying to figure it out on my own but I need some help getting started.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SQL` query in the question seems valid, you just need to add the rest of the tables and conditions to get the data you want.

> A user fills out the form and wants to search for all members with 
>   (members table)  zipcode = 11111 OR zipcode = 22222 (profiles table)
>   commitment = ANY, practice = ANY, gigs = 1, availability = ANY 
>   (skills table) lead_vocals = 1 and lead_guitar = 1 (genre table)
>   alternative = 1, modern_rock = 1, heavy_metal = 1

You already put half of the query in your request, except it is written in English and it happens that `SQL` is just a small subset of English.

The tables you mentioned appear in the `FROM` clause:

```
FROM members m
  INNER JOIN profiles p USING (member_id)
  INNER JOIN skills s USING (member_id)
  INNER JOIN genre g USING (member_id)
```

The conditions appear in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE p.gigs = 1
  AND s.lead_vocals = 1 AND s.guitar = 1
  AND g.alternative = 1 AND g.modern_rock = 1 AND g.heavy_metal = 1
```

The fields that allow `ANY` value do not appear in the query, they do not filter the results.

Searching more than one value for `zipcode` can be done using the `IN` operator:

```
  AND m.zipcode IN ('11111', '22222')
```

> At the end of the day the query just needs to return a list of results with member_id and login from the members table that match the criteria.

The fields to be returned goes to the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT m.member_id, m.login
```

Maybe you want to get the list of members in a specific order, for example sorted by their login names:

```
ORDER BY m.login
```

... or by some of their skills; put lead vocals in front of the list:

```
ORDER BY s.lead_vocals DESC
```

(order DESCending to get those having `1` in front of those having `0` in column `lead_vocals`

Now, if we put all together we get the complete query:

```
SELECT m.member_id, m.login
FROM members m
  INNER JOIN profiles p USING (member_id)
  INNER JOIN skills s USING (member_id)
  INNER JOIN genre g USING (member_id)
WHERE p.gigs = 1
  AND s.lead_vocals = 1 AND s.lead_guitar = 1
  AND g.alternative = 1 AND g.modern_rock = 1 AND g.heavy_metal = 1
  AND m.zipcode IN ('11111', '22222')
ORDER BY s.lead_vocals DESC, m.login
```

Because you get the information from user input you don't know in advance that `practice`, for example, is allowed to have `ANY` value. You need to compose the query from pieces, using the data received from the form.

Answer (score 0):

try this query.

```
select
m.*
from 
members m
left join Profiles p on p.member_id = m.id
left join Skills s on s.member_id = m.id
left join Genre g on g.member_id = m.id
where (m.zipcode = 11111 OR m.zipcode = 22222) and p.gigs = 1 and s.lead_vocals = 1 and s.lead_guitar = 1 and g.alternative = 1, g.modern_rock = 1, g.heavy_metal = 1
```